# Send SMS using Galaxy Tab (Wi-Fi)

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-tab

I'm looking for a way to send SMS messages from my Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (Wi-Fi GT-P5113). The unit is connected to the net via Wi-Fi.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's really a dup. The other question is about using Wi-Fi, but on a phone which would normally be able to send SMS over the cellular network. This question is about doing it on a device that doesn't have a cell radio or phone software. Borderline IMO.

Comment: Definitely a duplicate, a phone having a cell radio doesn't matter if Wi-Fi is being used and not the cell radio.  Cher, based on your comment below it appears that your *real* problem is activating WhatsApp without SMS -- I suggest you ask that specifically in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Several services exist to send SMS via the Internet. One of the most popular (an possibly most reliable) is [Google Voice](https://support.google.com/voice/answer/115116?hl=en).

Comment: My issue isn't so much routine sms communication, but a search for a way to approve my whatapp account. I managed to install the application on my tablet' even though it's not planned for this device. The first step prior to using the service, the  phone must be confirmed. My problem is however that the tablet is owned by an old lady' and she own an old mobile, not a smartphone. The the confirmation my skup the phone. I managed to send the needed code, but the delivery is stuck' maybe' since the tablet doesn't have a sim and the communication is thru wifi. That why Voice can't solve my problem

Comment: If the delivery is stuck, there is an issue with the message or the device receiving it.